# jersey working for media type text but not json or xml

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey

I have the following dependencies for jersey in my web application

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

when I use `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` or `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` i get a server error . Similarly if I try and use XML . Is it because of the libraries I am using ?

my java class

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/test")
public class test {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(test.class);



    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)  // works perfectly
    public Response getMsg()
    {
    logger.info("Inside getMsg()");

    String output = "hello world";

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

  /*   @GET                                      // I get a HTTP 500 , server error 
     @Path("/get")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public Track getTrackInJSON() {

         Track track = new Track();
         track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
         track.setSinger("Metallica");

         return track;
     }
    */


    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

        //String test = " hello world";
        return Response.status(201).entity(track).build();

    }


    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 //   @Produces(Me)

    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {
        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/getValue")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void createXML()
    {
        String result = " get the track";
        //        return result.createXML();
        // check this line

    }



        }
```

when I use a rest client to access the @GET resource I get this error :

```
<u>Internal Server Error</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
```

when I use the rest client to access the @POST resource I get this error:

```
<u>Internal Server Error</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
```

this is what I get from the Tomcat error logs

```
Jan 29, 2014 11:00:21 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.myProj.jsp.rest.Track, and Java type class com.gsipartners.apimgmtut
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.myProj.jsp.rest.Track, and Java type class com.myProj.jsp.rest.Track, and MIM
        ... 24 more
```

the Track class

```
public class Track {

    String title;
    String singer;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSinger() {
        return singer;
    }

    public void setSinger(String singer) {
        this.singer = singer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Track [title=" + title + ", singer=" + singer + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the error you have and the type of request you submit ? (or other elements of execution context)

Comment: added logs and class info

Answer (score 1):

You should annotate your `Track` class with `JAXB` annotations and Jersey will use its MessageBodyWriter to serialize/marshall the returned entity (track) into the response outputstream. Or you'll need to provide your own implementation of `MessageBodyWriter` for the `Track` type to write the serialized form in the response outputstream. Otherwise, Jersey doesn't know how to do it.

Comment: what should I be annotating it with? it is simple POJO class . I have put up the class in the question to demonstrate .

Comment: You should use the `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement` annotation on the type and `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement` on fields you need to rename/exclude during marshalling/unmarshalling. See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.17/json.html